# What's the difference between `--` and `\textendash`?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

It looks like `--` and `\textendash` have different line-breaking behaviour in LaTeX. I'd assumed that they would just insert an en dash character, and then act the same, but it looks like they don't from this [example](https://www.overleaf.com/read/dgcctrtmktrc):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

I'm going to write a really, really, really long numerical range: 10000000\textendash 20000000 which should overflow the justification box, which you can see from my continued typing below the above line.

I'm going to write a really, really, really long numerical range: 10000000--20000000 which should overflow the justification box, which you can see from my continued typing below the above line.

% This paragraph uses an en dash character directly
I'm going to write a really, really, really long numerical range: 10000000–20000000 which should overflow the justification box, which you can see from my continued typing below the above line.

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Why is this the case, and are there any other differences I should be looking out for?

Note that inserting an en dash directly (the last paragraph) also seems to act like `\textendash`, which makes me wonder if `--` is truly an en dash?

Comment: `--` are two hyphens, which are later on converted as a ligature into the en-dash glyph used by `\textendash`. In pdflatex this happens after it has decided that hyphenation is allowed after a hyphen. In lualatex the behaviour is different.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer aha! That's good to know — if you post as an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: Another difference is that `--` is easier to type, easier to read for humans but also exportable asis  with the traditional  copy & paste method to  LibreOffice and rmarkdown, (relevant if collaborators are not LaTeX fans, for instance).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `--`, there is a feasible break points, because the ligature ends with the default hyphen character. (Pedantic note: this happens only if the `\hyphenchar` parameter for the current font is the hyphen.)

On the other hand, `\textendash` is essentially equivalent to `\char21` and since this has nothing to do with the hyphen character, no break point is present after it. The same happens if you type `–` U+2013, because in pdflatex this is converted to `\textendash`.

Comment: So, `--` is the advised thing to type?

Comment: @Gaussler It depends on whether you want to allow a line break past it.

Comment: In these kinds of cases, one usually wants to make a global, consistent choice. Either it is always allowed at “–”, or it’s not. And I think the literal tradition says that they should be allowed, doesn’t it?

Comment: @Gaussler That really depends on different typographic traditions and personal preferences.

Comment: Anyway, when are you going to ask your first question on TeX.SX? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Possibly 2022/02/30

Comment: Why exactly then?

Comment: @Gaussler He offers riddles to keep us in suspense.  Time to get out the secret decoder ring...hmmm..30 = 2x2x2x2x2-2. Wait!...wait!...decode coming through now: B-E---S-U-R-E---T-O----D-R-I-N-K---Y-O-U-R---O-V-A-L-T-I-N-E ?? (ref: https://www.cbr.com/movie-legends-revealed-there-was-no-decoder-ring-in-a-christmas-story/)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I am so ashamed that I did not figure that out immediately. It was so obvious from the context. `;-)`

Comment: Don't feel bad, @Gaussler, I still can't decode his ultimate riddle...you know, the one activated by `\ExplSyntaxOn`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes We shall take some time figuring that one out. Anyway, I’m really looking forward to February 30, 2022 when egreg finally reveals his long-awaited question. February 30 is always such a good occasion for so many things.

Comment: @Gaussler Yes, I think 2022 is a fabled leap-leap year, is it not?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sure. That’s the year when February has 32 days.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that I ran this file through all three TeX engines. pdfTeX, as expected, gives the results described. XeTeX, correctly breaks at the – in all three paragraphs. LuaTeX, surprisingly, does not break at *any* of the en dashes. This last seems to be very bad behavior. I'm sticking with my recommendation for people who want to use Unicode input to prefer XeLaTeX over the other engines.